# Password transformation method for custom editText field

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

In my application, I have a custom edit text for OTP inputs, I want to make a transformation method for this view so users can see the actual input for a second and it replaces with a bullet. Just like in native edittext with password input.

```
private class PinTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {

        private char BULLET = '\u2B24';

        @Override
        public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
            return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
        }

        private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
            private final CharSequence source;

            public PasswordCharSequence(@NonNull CharSequence source) {
                this.source = source;
            }

            @Override
            public int length() {
                return source.length();
            }

            @Override
            public char charAt(int index) {
                return BULLET;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
                return new PasswordCharSequence(this.source.subSequence(start, end));
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is my transformation method extends from PasswordTransformation method. It can replaces my input with Bullets perfectly but I can't manage to show the input for a few seconds, how can I achieve this?

Comment: changing input type at runtime doesn' work ?

Comment: Change InputType runtime it will  be a good idea.

Comment: the thing is I listen to the inputs until it reaches to end and send the otp to the server, there is no button, so runtime check wouldnt be efficent

Comment: you can add a handler that will wait for few milliseconds befor changing to bulet